# Get Data from textfile and put it into a Jaggarrd Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
String Service;
BufferedReader in = null;
BufferedReader readn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filepath)));

//Job [] dj =  new Job[vlinenumber];
String linen="";
while ((linen = readn.readLine()) != null) {
    //System.out.println (line);
    String[] vem =linen.split(",");
    int j=linen.length();



    String regiration=vem[0];
    String make=vem[1];
    String Model=vem[2];
    String Year=vem[3];
    String odo=vem[4];


    int ant=vem.length;
    System.out.println(ant+"this is ");

    String cv=vem[5];

    if(ant==3){
        String aaa= vem[6];
    }

    if(ant==4){
        String aaa= vem[7];
    }
```

Textfile example:

```
OWNED,Ford,Falcon XL Ute,2008,167000,14331
FAST,Maserati,Quattroporte Sport GT,2007,48960,14321,90309
OK2BL8,Morris,Minor 1000,1969,567340,14315,90311
```

Comment: What do you want? What have you got? Any errors? If so, post the error here.

Comment: create a model class `Details` define set and get method that will be better.

Comment: I dont get an error when displaying it its just that i cant assign  the variable vem[6] array to anything because not all the sign hace as many strings.

Comment: I do have an object class for the data with getters and setters but how do u pass an array of jobs[] to it

Comment: the last two numbers are both unique identifers and some lines mix them up

Answer (score 2):

you should try like this:

```
     public class Test {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader readn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "d:\\data.txt")));

        String linen = "";
        List<Details> dList = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((linen = readn.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = linen.split(",");
            Details d = new Details();
        if (data.length > 0) {
            d.setReg(data[0]);
        }
        if (data.length > 1) {
            d.setMake(data[1]);
        }
        if (data.length > 2) {
            d.setModel(data[2]);
        }
        if (data.length > 3) {
            d.setYear(data[3]);
        }
        if (data.length > 4) {
            d.setOdo(data[4]);
        }
        if (data.length > 5) {
            d.setCv(data[5]);
        }
        if (data.length > 6) {
            d.setAa(data[6]);
        }
        if (data.length > 7) {
            d.setAa(data[7]);
        }
            System.out.println(d);
            dList.add(d);

        }
    }

}
```

Model class :

```
  class Details {
    String reg;
    String make;
    String model;
    String year;
    String odo;
    String aa;
    String cv;

    public String getReg() {
        return reg;
    }

    public void setReg(String reg) {
        this.reg = reg;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getOdo() {
        return odo;
    }

    public void setOdo(String odo) {
        this.odo = odo;
    }

    public String getAa() {
        return aa;
    }

    public void setAa(String aa) {
        this.aa = aa;
    }

    public String getCv() {
        return cv;
    }

    public void setCv(String cv) {
        this.cv = cv;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return reg + "\t" + make + "\t" + model + "\t" + year + "\t" + odo+"\t"+cv+"\t"+aa;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the line will have one customerId at the end and the line can have many jobIDs at the end aswell.

Comment: check condition if data.length>4 than set that value too.

Comment: how would you do that if lines were diffrent lengths though?

Comment: what do you mean? lines were diff.?

Comment: could you please tell me which all fields it can be.

Comment: see the textfile example the last 3 ints after the date contain one custId which links to another tiextfile and 2 job idds from another textfile

Comment: @alex tell me max field the file can have.

Comment: 8 fields Im pretty sure

Comment: declare varibale in model class `Details` as much fields you have and setter and getter for the same and set the value in your `main`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63572/discussion-between-rustam-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick, but you should consider using a more complex structure (entity classes):

```
        String fileContent = "OWNED,Ford,Falcon XL Ute,2008,167000,14331\nFAST,Maserati,Quattroporte Sport GT,2007,48960,14321,90309\nOK2BL8,Morris,Minor 1000,1969,567340,14315,90311";

        String[] rows = fileContent.split("\n");

        String data[][] = new String[rows.length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            String row = rows[i];
            data[i] = row.split(",");
        }
```

This code will create a 2-dimensional array with the content of your file. For this data it should look like this:

```
data[0][0] -> "OWNED"
data[0][1] -> "Ford"
[...]
data[1][0] -> "FAST"
```

As I understood it is important for you that the array (2d) containing the values can have a variable length. This works with this approach.